# Java how can i get an enum type with a probability

Tags: java

Hey I need help with my code. I have different enums with different probability. I get my random float with java.util.Random . I want when random has e.g. the probability of 17% it will automatically find out which enum is closest for this value. Thx for helping

```
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   enum Types{
       TYPE_1(0.20f),
       TYPE_2(0.05f),
       TYPE_3(0.30f),
       TYPE_40.12f),
       TYPE_5(0.03f),

       @Getter
       private final float chance;
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have two enums with `0.05f` each. What means "closest" in this case?

Comment: @Marvin Sorry I made a mistake should be 0.03f

Comment: @illuminator3 I have tried many things to calculate the closest distance but without success.

Comment: Can this "closest" check return multiple types?

Comment: @aksappy No it should only return one enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if all you want is the type that is the closest and not all the *types* that are closest to an input.

```java
enum Types {
    TYPE_1(0.20f),
    TYPE_2(0.20f),
    TYPE_3(0.30f),
    TYPE_4(.12f),
    TYPE_5(0.03f);

    private final float chance;

    Types(float f) {
        this.chance = f;
    }
}
```

```java
public static Optional<Types> closest(float f) {
        return Arrays.stream(Types.values())
                .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(type -> Math.abs(type.chance - f)));
}
```

closest returns an Optional in here, depending upon your needs you can add an `orElse` or `ifPresentOrElse` or the many methods in Optional that suits.

Comment: @aksahappy thanks very much its working nice!